# QWeb docker image

Tags: docker, robotframework, qweb

Has anyone been able to build a docker image that contains robot framework and QWeb installations? I'm able to build an image, but running tests with it doesn't succeed. It says 'Resource file 'Qweb' does not exist'.

Dockerfile

```
from python:3

RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \ 
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN pip install robotframework

RUN pip install qweb

ENTRYPOINT ["robot"]

CMD ["-d", "/opt/robotframework/reports", "--outputdir", "/opt/robotframework/reports", "--loglevel", "INFO", "--include", "QWeb", "/opt/robotframework/tests"]
```

Comment: In case anyone else tries to reproduce the issue, keep in mind that the packages aren't available for arm so you need to cross-build if you're on an apple silicon chip like so `$ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64` and then add tag and context

Comment: can you add the output where you get the error and how you run the image?

Comment: command:

docker -H unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock run   --net=host --rm --shm-size=2g   -v /$PWD/reports:/opt/robotframework/reports:Z   -v /$PWD/robot:/opt/robotframework/tests:Z   -v /$PWD/python:/opt/robotframework/python:Z   -e PYTHONPATH=/opt/robotframework/python   qweb_container:latest

output:

Tests
==============================================================================
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/opt/robotframework/tests/QWebSuite.robot' on line 7: Resource file 'Qweb' does not exist.

Comment: I have built a few QWeb containers. I couldn't reproduce your problem, but I got an error about DISPLAY missing. I usually run QWeb inside xvfb.

Comment: @Pekka, do you have a working QWeb container I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare-bones Dockerfile. I am running it with this command: `docker run -v $PWD/robot:/opt/robot/Tests -v $PWD/output:/opt/robot/output -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm qweb`

```
FROM python:3.11.3

# Update our system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --yes && pip install --upgrade pip

# Install xvfb
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends -y software-properties-common \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y scrot xvfb xauth zip

#Installing chrome and chrome driver for selenium
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64]  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y google-chrome-stable

RUN curl -o /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /tmp \
    && mv /tmp/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -rf /tmp/chromedriver-linux64

# Set the locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Install Robot Framework and dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir robotframework==6.0.2 QWeb==2.2.1

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT  xvfb-run robot -d /opt/robot/output /opt/robot/Tests
```